# Add network profile into the iOS 10 application

Tags: swift, xcode, ios10, apple-configurator

I have a network app written on swift for iOS 10.x. The app needs specific network configuration (related to Wi-Fi) and it's working properly in a case when I creating network profile manually using Apple Configurator 2 and then push this profile to iOS 10 device.
**Question 1:** Is it possible to include network profile into the iOS 10 app and install this profile with the app automatically?
**Question 2:** Is there some way to install network profile to iOS 10 devices without Apple Configurator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/iPhoneOTAConfiguration/Introduction/Introduction.html

> There are four ways to deploy configuration profiles:
>
> - By physically connecting the device
> - In an email message
> - On a webpage
> - Using over-the air configuration as described in this document

Maybe you can force the user to open a web page using a link which points to the profile. Make sure that if the user clicks on the link that the link gets opened in safari not in you app.

Comment: You can technically start a web server inside your app too, and serve it from there. See https://github.com/swisspol/GCDWebServer

Comment: Thanks, but it's heavy solution for my app.